# generic type evaluate in mvc 1 c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

i have the following code that needs to evaluate its type although Im not sure how to do this in mvc 1?  The show method at the bottom of the example highlights the problem where I need to evaluate whether the type is Car or Boat.  Can anyone suggest how to do this please!
Many thanks
James

```
public interface IPanel
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class CarPanel : IPanel
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Hello Car"; }
    }
}

public class BoatPanel : IPanel
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Hello Boat"; }
    }
}

...

var list = new List<IPanel>();

list.Add(new BoatPanel());
list.Add(new CarPanel());


// In the view

foreach (var p in ViewData.Model.Panels)
{ 
    <% Html.RenderAction<PanelController>(x => x.Show()); %> 
}


// PanelController


public ActionResult Show()
{
    var model = <T> // Problem: Am I a Boat or Car?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `is` operator.

```
if(model is BoatPanel)
{
    //your code
}
if(model is CarPanel)
{
    //your code
}
```

The [is operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is used for checking if a generic object is of a desired type.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Please write descriptive answers, that, could prove useful for future visitors of this question/post.

Comment: @askmish : 'll try to improve it. Thanks :)

Comment: great.  Let me experiment and I'll update you!  Looks very promising at this point!